# Automating commands in Blender?

Tags: add-on

[image]

Starting with Adobe line of products, actions gave me life-saving automation functionality, is there any similar thing like this packed inside blender? or are there anyone who's developed an addon?   cheers! :)

Comment: Your question is too generic, addons themselves are automations for Blender. You can create your own script if you learn BPy, or you can use other people's scripts. It would be more clear if you can explain what do you need to achieve using automation.

Comment: thanks, i'll remember this in the near future. been thinking to learn Py anyways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always look at your command history, open a Python Console next to it and copy/paste the commands.[image]

If you want something more GUI-like, you'd have to get into a Python Addon.